# changing css custom cursor via url(...)

Tags: html, css, cursor

Here's a link if this would help:

[lovesongforever.com/nancytributes](http://www.lovesongforever.com/nancytributes)

Trying to add a custom css cursor.  If I try to use a standard cursor for 
testing purposes, e.g., "wait", cursor change happens properly ... but NOT
for custom css cursor via url(...)

Couldn't get the css cursor spec to work without ", help"

```css
.surpriseCursor {
 cursor: url(clapping_hands.gif), help;   /* max size = 32 X 32 pixels */
}
```

```html
<a name="surprise"> </a>
<a href="#surprise" onclick="PlaySound('applause', 'applause.mp3'); return false">
<img class="surpriseCursor" src="Broken_Heart.gif"><p>
</a>
```

Comment: This code should display your custom cursor provided the path is correct. Is your question, why do you need to include the text 'help'?

Comment: The path is at the same level as the .html, so there's no intervening folders.  Why ,help ... I wish I knew ... if I delete ,help the cursor does not change.  If I just have cursor: wait or some other standard one, the cursor shown is wait or whatever I use there.  It's the custom url(...) that does not change as it should ... unless I put ,help there.  TOTALLY INSANE

Comment: It's not insane, it's just a backup property in case there's an issue with the image. It's in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a default cursor in case your custom one doesn't load, without it you don't have a correct CSS property. As per W3C:

> A comma separated list of URLs to custom cursors. Note: Always specify
>   a generic cursor at the end of the list, in case none of the
>   URL-defined cursors can be used

This should be set in most cases (definitely yours) to auto.

**The correct code:**

```
.surpriseCursor {
    cursor: url(clapping_hands.gif), auto;
}
```

**See link:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp